# Odd vertical space combining footmisc with hang option and bigfoot

Tags: spacing, footnotes, footmisc, bigfoot

Trying to combine the  `hang` option of `footmisc` with the `bigfoot` package (later to be used for more footnote registers) I am getting an odd line inserted between the footnotes. If I comment out the line `\usepackage{bigfoot}`, or omit the `hang` option, the footnotes get formatted with normal inter line space, just this combination doesn't seem to work well. Example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
%\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\begin{document}
Some text\footnote{A footnote.}\footnote{And one more.}
\end{document}
```

How do I get this combination to work without the extra vertical space?

Answer (score 2):

There is a \par too much in this combination

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
%\usepackage{footmisc}
\makeatletter
 \long\def\@makefntext#1{%
    \ifFN@hangfoot
      \bgroup
      \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
        \ifdim\footnotemargin>0pt
          \hb@xt@\footnotemargin{\@makefnmark\hss}%
        \else
          \@makefnmark
        \fi
      }%
      \leftmargin\wd\@tempboxa
      \rightmargin\z@
      \linewidth \columnwidth
      \advance \linewidth -\leftmargin
      \parshape \@ne \leftmargin \linewidth
      \footnotesize
      \@setpar{{\@@par}}%
      \leavevmode
      \llap{\box\@tempboxa}%
      \parskip\hangfootparskip\relax
      \parindent\hangfootparindent\relax
    \else
      \parindent1em
      \noindent
      \ifdim\footnotemargin>\z@
        \hb@xt@ \footnotemargin{\hss\@makefnmark}%
      \else
        \ifdim\footnotemargin=\z@
          \llap{\@makefnmark}%
        \else
          \llap{\hb@xt@ -\footnotemargin{\@makefnmark\hss}}%
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
    \footnotelayout#1%
    \ifFN@hangfoot
      %\par<-----
      \egroup
    \fi
  }  

\usepackage{bigfoot}

\begin{document}
Some text\footnote{A footnote.}\footnote{And one more}
\end{document}
```

[image]