Footmisc hanging option produces empty lines when bigfoot is loaded
I am using bigfoot for multiple levels of footnotes and want to style these footnotes with the help of the package footmisc. As I need hanging footnotes, I tried the "hang" option of the footmisc package.
While the hanging works, this produces an empty line after each footnote, which is very unpleasant. Is there a way to get hanging footnotes when bigfoot is loaded without those empty lines?
The loading order of the packages had no impact, and the empty lines appear on every footnote level, so all footnotes are affected. The other footmisc-options I use (bottom,multiple,stable) also had no impact.
I tried the following two workarounds, but they had no effect, so any help would be appreciated:
\renewcommand{\hangfootparskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{10pt}
MWE:
\documentclass{book}
\RequirePackage{bigfoot}
\RequirePackage[hang]{footmisc} % hang produces empty lines between footnotes.

\begin{document}
    Foo\footnote{Bar}
    Foo\footnote{Bar}
\end{document}


See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242161/odd-vertical-space-combining-footmisc-with-hang-option-and-bigfoot

Thanks for sharing this post. Unfortunately the solution presented there has an unwanted sideeffect: The empty lines are gone, but now the footnotemarks appear "in margine" as is shown in the image provided by Ulrike Fischer in her post.

After I reported the issue to the maintainer of the footmisc package, he came up with the following solution, which has to be added in the preamble of the document:
\makeatletter
\def\@finalstrut#1{%
  \unskip
  \ifhmode \nobreak \vrule
  \else
    \ifdim \prevdepth=-\@m\p@
    \else
      \vskip-\prevdepth
    \fi
    \hrule
  \fi
  \@width\z@\@height\z@\@depth\dp#1}
\makeatother

This patch should become obsolete once the next LaTeX-Version is released, but for now it does the job:
Cf. https://github.com/FrankMittelbach/fmitex-footmisc/issues/14
